# Article, Comment and User relationship in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I made a blog where you can CRUD articles and post comments. Everything is fine and working good.

I just want to make Laravel to do the magic when the User posts a comment to an article and instead of hard-coding `article_id` and `user_id`.

```
Comment::create([
    'body' => request('body'),
    'article_id' => $article->id,
    'user_id' => Auth::User()->id]
);
```

Is it possible to use Laravel's Eloquent relationships to chain up some functions/methods and simplify it a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If `user_id` and `article_id` are both `nullable` (which I doubt, but let's assume they are) you can use Eloquent like this:

```
$user = Auth::User()->id;
$article = Article::find($request('article_id'));
$comment = Comment::create(['body' => $request('body')]);
$comment->article()->associate($article);
$comment->user()->associate($user);
```

Otherwise, another method that can improve it a little bit is something like this:

```
$article = Article::find('article_id');
$article->comments()->save(new Comment([
    'body' => request('body');
    'user_id' => Auth::User()->id;
]);
```

The same can be done for the user too.